# Flutter: How to make user login automatically after register successfully?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, splash-screen

I've bought a Flutter source code and finding ways to build a function to make user **login automatically after register successfully** in my app.

My app uses Firebase and email is authentication for register.

Users just need to put any emails with valid format like abc@xyz.com (not same old emails in database) and a password, **press Sign up button then they will be automatically logged in and redirected to homepage**.

This is a sample lines in register_view.dart file.

I try to write this code nearly last lines: **Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoutePaths.home,);** but after pressing Sign up button users are redirected to splash screens and not logged in.

Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you very much!

```
class __SignInButtonWidgetState extends State<_SignInButtonWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: PsDimens.space32, right: PsDimens.space32),
      child: PSButtonWidget(
        colorData: PsColors.buttonColor,
        hasShadow: false,
        width: double.infinity,
        titleText: Utils.getString(context, 'register__register'),
        onPressed: () async {
          if (widget.nameTextEditingController!.text.isEmpty) {
            callWarningDialog(context,
                Utils.getString(context, 'warning_dialog__input_name'));
          } else if (widget.emailTextEditingController!.text.isEmpty) {
            callWarningDialog(context,
                Utils.getString(context, 'warning_dialog__input_email'));
          } else if (widget.passwordTextEditingController!.text.isEmpty) {
            callWarningDialog(context,
                Utils.getString(context, 'warning_dialog__input_password'));
          } else {
            if(Utils.checkEmailFormat(widget.emailTextEditingController!.text.trim())!){
            await widget.provider.signUpWithEmailId(
                context,
                widget.onRegisterSelected,
                widget.nameTextEditingController!.text,
                widget.emailTextEditingController!.text.trim(),
                widget.passwordTextEditingController!.text);
            }else{
              callWarningDialog(context,
                Utils.getString(context, 'warning_dialog__email_format'));
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: what does this function return?
await widget.provider.signUpWithEmailId(
                context,
                widget.onRegisterSelected,
                widget.nameTextEditingController!.text,
                widget.emailTextEditingController!.text.trim(),
                widget.passwordTextEditingController!.text);
            }

Answer (score 0):

When you got your result from

```
String data = await widget.provider.signUpWithEmailId(
            context,
            widget.onRegisterSelected,
            widget.nameTextEditingController!.text,
            widget.emailTextEditingController!.text.trim(),
            widget.passwordTextEditingController!.text);
```

Store data in variable after send it to success page.

Comment: Thank you, MohitJadav86! Can you combine 2 your above codes into my source code? Sorry because I'm new to Flutter.

Comment: below answer is already combined you have to just replace it

Comment: Which one, sir? I have tried both of your codes step-by-step and gotten same erros.
Can you review your code again and insert it into my above sample code with correct every , ; ( ) {}?
I am really grateful to you!

Comment: await widget.provider.signUpWithEmailId(
        context,
        widget.onRegisterSelected,
        widget.nameTextEditingController!.text,
        widget.emailTextEditingController!.text.trim(),
        widget.passwordTextEditingController!.text).then((value) => Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoutePaths.home,));

Comment: try this one it will help

Comment: Thank you but nothing happen, sir. After pressing Signup in app, users will see the splash screen without logging in although their account is shown in database and backend. 

I see your code "String data" before. So what have I to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
await widget.provider.signUpWithEmailId(
    context,
    widget.onRegisterSelected,
    widget.nameTextEditingController!.text,
    widget.emailTextEditingController!.text.trim(),
    widget.passwordTextEditingController!.text).then((value) => Navigator.pushNamed(context, RoutePaths.home,));
```